# Cross compiling with arm-linux-gnueabihf

Tags: gcc, compilation, centos, arm

I am quite new to cross compiling. After downloading the arm-linux-gnueabihf tool from [arm](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads). I tried to use the binary called arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ and arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc to compile my code. My command looks something like:

```
 ~/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Isrc -I/usr/include -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O0 -g3 -D__DEBUG_BUILD__ -DDEVELOPMENT -MMD -c -o "Debug/src/BatteryStatus.o" "src/BatteryStatus.cpp"
```

I immediately run into this issue:

```
~/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/stdlib.h:133:35: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __HAVE_FLOAT16 && __GLIBC_USE (IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT)
```

It's weird that the issue happens in the tool chain, I would expect some incompatibilities in the libraries I am using. The environment entails CentOS 7.2, c++ 11 and I am compiling for an ARM 32-bit target on a x86_64 host machine. Building a simple hello world program went fine, it compiled and ran successfully on the target machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pointing to your native header files directory, `/usr/include`, in your build command. This is very likely the cause of your problem. Try this command instead:

```
~/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Isrc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O0 -g3 -D__DEBUG_BUILD__ -DDEVELOPMENT -MMD -c -o "Debug/src/BatteryStatus.o" "src/BatteryStatus.cpp
```

The default directories used by the toolchain can be displayed using:

```
echo | /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v -x c -E -

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: /tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm8--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/src/gcc/configure --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix= --with-sysroot=/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc --with-build-sysroot=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm8--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/build-arm-linux-gnueabihf/install//arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc --with-bugurl=https://bugs.linaro.org/ --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-shared --disable-libssp --disable-libmudflap --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-gmp=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm8--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/build-arm-linux-gnueabihf/host-tools --with-mpfr=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm8--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/build-arm-linux-gnueabihf/host-tools --with-mpc=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm8--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/build-arm-linux-gnueabihf/host-tools --with-isl=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm8--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/build-arm-linux-gnueabihf/host-tools --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=neon --with-float=hard --with-arch=armv7-a --with-pkgversion='GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 8.3-2019.03 (arm-rel-8.36)'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 8.3-2019.03 (arm-rel-8.36)) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-E'  '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=neon' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv7-a+simd'
 /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/cc1 -E -quiet -v -iprefix /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/ -isysroot /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc - -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtls-dialect=gnu -marm -march=armv7-a+simd
ignoring duplicate directory "/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/local/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include
 /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include-fixed
 /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
 /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
COMPILER_PATH=/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/:/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../libexec/gcc/:/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/:/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/:/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/:/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/:/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-E'  '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=neon' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv7-a+simd'
```

That is, on my system, the correct, default directories for the header files would be:

```
 /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include
 /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include-fixed
 /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
 /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include
```

and not `/usr/include`.

Comment: The reason I added /usr/include, was that I have some third party libraries in there. Do I have to copy all of them over to  /opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include?

Comment: @wenjie-zhong if your code is located, say, in src, you should certainly copy .h and .a files for those libraries into, say, src/include and src/lib directories. Then you should use -Isrc/include and -Lsrc/lib options. Please note that you need to cross-compile those libraries first. But you definitively need to remove your native /usr/include directory from the search path.

Comment: Got it, I was having trouble with dbus-c++ header files. Guess I have to cross compile that too. Thanks for the help.